# Create an empty istream to be filled from a method call

Tags: c++, pointers, dereference

Im trying to create an method that returns an istream. Problem is i cant get an empty reference to pass to the method for filling.

In my main:

```
std::istream &is;//<-Initialized
is = NetPoco::getJson(is,"URL");
std::stringstream ss;
StreamCopier::copyStream(is,ss);
printf(ss.str().c_str());
```

In my getJson():

```
    istream& NetPoco::getJson(istream& is,string url){
    try
     {
           ....
           istream &is = session.receiveResponse(res);
           return is;
          }
```

Im passing the is from main since otherwise it seems to get de references.
What is the correct(best practise) method of making a method returning an istream or a pointer to an istream to main to be parsed there.

Answer (score 2):

You need to initialise references when they are declared. Rewrite your code as follows:

```
int main() {
    std::istream &is = NetPoco::getJson("URL");
    std::stringstream ss;
    StreamCopier::copyStream(is,ss);
    std::cout << ss.str();
}

//Removed `istream& is` parameter. It is not needed
std::istream& NetPoco::getJson(string url){
    try {
        //...
        std::istream &is = session.receiveResponse(res);
        return is;
    }
    catch(...) {
        //...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's always good practice to initialize the reference objects when they are declared

```
std::istream &is = NetPoco::getJson(is,"URL");
```

if you don't initialize reference object it's an error.

Comment: Should there be an ampersand?

Comment: The stream object represent a handle to streams of data. iostream cannot be assigned or copy. It has to be a reference. ampersand is needed.